# pandas operation between dataframe and plot

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, bar-chart

I have two dataframe. Let's say:

```
x1=[{"dates":'2018-01-31',"rev":-2},
{"dates":'2018-02-28',"rev":-5},
{"dates":'2018-03-31',"rev":-7},
{"dates":'2018-04-30',"rev":-8},
{"dates":'2018-05-31',"rev":-9},
{"dates":'2018-06-30',"rev":-2},
{"dates":'2018-07-31',"rev":1},
{"dates":'2018-08-31',"rev":2},
{"dates":'2018-09-30',"rev":3},
{"dates":'2018-10-31',"rev":4},
{"dates":'2018-11-30',"rev":4},
{"dates":'2018-12-31',"rev":5}]


x2=[{"dates":'2018-01-31',"rev":-5},
{"dates":'2018-02-28',"rev":-9},
{"dates":'2018-03-31',"rev":-9},
{"dates":'2018-04-30',"rev":-6},
{"dates":'2018-05-31',"rev":-1},
{"dates":'2018-06-30',"rev":-2},
{"dates":'2018-07-31',"rev":-14},
{"dates":'2018-08-31',"rev":2},
{"dates":'2018-09-30',"rev":3},
{"dates":'2018-10-31',"rev":4},
{"dates":'2018-11-30',"rev":-4},
{"dates":'2018-12-31',"rev":5}]


df1=pd.DataFrame(x1)
df1["dates"]=pd.to_datetime(df1.dates)
df2=pd.DataFrame(x2)
df2["dates"]=pd.to_datetime(df2.dates)
```

After that, I have to execute some operations:

```
dR1 = ((df1['rev'] - df2['rev'] ) / df2['rev']) * 10
dR2 = ((df1['rev'] - df2['rev'] ) / df2['rev']) * 50
```

Now I would like to plot dR1 and dR2 by taking advantage of both dateformat and pandas.
Following a previous post suggestion:

```
ax = dR1.merge(dR2, on='dates', how='outer').plot.bar(x='dates',color=['red','blue'],width=0.4)
```

However, it seems that both dR1 and dR2 are series and not dataframes.

What do I get wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what are you trying to plot?

Answer (score 1):

Each column in DataFrame is a data series.  So when you are doing manipulations on the column, your result is a series too.

i.e. `((df1['rev'] - df2['rev'] ) / df2['rev']) * 10` does manipulations on series `df1['rev']` and `df2['rev']` and returns a series.  (Note that this assumes that all your data is in correct order, and has exact same length. Unless you have very careful preprocessing, that's a very risky assumption.)

I'm guessing what you wanted to do is get some relationship between the two 'rev' fields on the same date?

I suggest try the following after you get your `df1` and `df2` declared:

```
## change `rev` column name in each, so you know where they coming from. (in df1 name it `rev1` in df2 `rev2`)

df1.rename(columns={'rev':'rev1'}, inplace=True)
df2.rename(columns={'rev':'rev2'}, inplace=True)

## now merge them into 1 dataframe with one date column and `rev1` and `rev2`:
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='dates', how='outer')
```

This will make sure that your rev1 and rev2 correspond to correct dates.

At this point you will have a DataFrame `df`:

```
    dates   rev1    rev2
0   2018-01-31  -2  -5
1   2018-02-28  -5  -9
2   2018-03-31  -7  -9
3   2018-04-30  -8  -6
4   2018-05-31  -9  -1
5   2018-06-30  -2  -2
6   2018-07-31  1   -14
7   2018-08-31  2   2
8   2018-09-30  3   3
9   2018-10-31  4   4
10  2018-11-30  4   -4
11  2018-12-31  5   5
```

Now create the two operations (or any amount) that you want, eg:

```
df['dR1']=((df['rev1']-df['rev2'])/df['rev2'])*10
df['dR2']=((df['rev1']-df['rev2'])/df['rev2'])*50
```

Note: each operation creates a series, that is attached as column in your overall DataFrame `df`.

Now it's time to plot!

```
## plot dates and dR1
ax1 = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='dates', y='dR1', color='r')

## plot dates and dR2, but set the axis (ax) to be same as in the first one, if you want these to be on the same plot    
ax2 = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='dates', y='dR2', color='b', ax=ax1)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: thanks. Could you please give a glue to the prepossessing part?
Now all data have same length and dates but I don't know about future possible simulation. Thanks

Comment: By doing it in the way I suggested, the data will work even if the dates are not aligned, in the two datasets, because I join. them (`pd.merge`) before doing computations.  In the pd.merge() right now I'm doing 'outer', meaning that if one column has a date, and the other doesn't , the value will still be there.  You can also do a 'left' join, where you would decide which table takes precedence.  Or 'inner' join, if you want to use only dates that have values in both datasets.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why dR1 and dR2 are series because you are performing operation on pandas dataframe which will return you pandas series. You can pd.DataFrame function to solve this

```
dR1 = pd.DataFrame(((df1['rev'] - df2['rev'] ) / df2['rev']) * 10)
dR2 = pd.DataFrame(((df1['rev'] - df2['rev'] ) / df2['rev']) * 50)
dR1['dates'] = df1['dates']
dR2['dates'] = df1['dates']
```